# How to parse a string of characters into groups when the characters are in a row column order?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that can be of any length.

`aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooopppqqqrrrsssttt`

I want to be able to get all the groups of characters from it.  The number of groups in the string is unlimited.

A group is made up of 3 columns, and 4 rows.  So if I split that string up into groups, it would look like this...

```
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee
fff  ggg  hhh  iii  jjj
kkk  lll  mmm  nnn  ooo
ppp  qqq  rrr  sss  ttt
```

So the first group of characters would be...

`aaa fff kkk ppp`

Second...

`bbb ggg lll qqq`

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- First of use RegExp and `match()` to get 1D array of strings like `["aaa","bbb",...]`.
- Then divide the the length of this array by no of groups you want to make i.e `4` in this case. Lets name this `x`
- Then use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the array. And use `[]` as initial value of accumulator.
- Now element at check if index of current element modulus `x` then `push()` the value to it. Other wise make an empty array at that place.

```js
let str = 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooopppqqqrrrsssttt'


let groups = str.match(/(.)\1+/g);
let x = groups.length/4;

let res = groups.reduce((ac,a,i) => {
  if(!ac[i%x]) ac[i%x] = [];
  ac[i%x].push(a);
  return ac;
},[]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula for grabbing the index of a particular group for a given x, y pair is:

```
index = (x + (y * 5))*3;
```

5 Because you have 5 columns. 3 because each column is 3 characters wide.

So the start index of a column will be your column index × 3.

Next you'll want to figure out how high your matrix is. If you are guaranteed full rows, then you can say the height is the length of the string ÷ 15. That's because each row is 15 characters wide.

So to get the last index of your column you'll want (column index + ((height-1) × 5)) × 3).

(height - 1) because y is 0 indexed.

Now you have your start and end indices. The next thing will be to loop through the string one row width at a time from your start index to your end index, grabbing 3 characters as you go and adding the 3 characters to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` to split the sting into small arrays. then,`map()` and `slice()` the big array into groups.

```js
const str = 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooopppqqqrrrsssttt'
const lettersArr = str.match(/([a-z])\1*/g)
var chunkSize = 4;

const groups =  lettersArr.map( function(e,i){ 
     return i%chunkSize===0 ? lettersArr.slice(i,i+chunkSize) : null; 
}).filter((e) =>e);

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: OP don't want to divide array in chunks. He want to group the columns.